# How To Use My Switchable GPUs?

Tags: games, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, intel-cpu

I recently moved away from W10 due to it fucking up after a fresh installation.

I have Intel HD 3000 & AMD HD 6470M on my laptop; with 4 GB RAM and i5 2430M

During installation I checked "Install additional drivers" etc

I am a gamer; even though I have a craptop atm. I play Insurgency, Rocket League, ARMA 3 etc.

I want to make sure I can get the most out of Linux while gaming but as far as I can see I cannot edit my GPU settings regarding AMD and Intel; or make AMD go High Performance etc by right clicking the desktop etc.

1) How do I make sure the OS uses both GPUs, but AMD mostly for gaming?

2) How do I make sure AMD and Intel drivers are installed?

3) How do I edit GPU settings like I said above?

All the help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Tried running insurgency (A game that I used to get 40-60ish FPS in W10)

I can hardly maintain 20....

Please help me!

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out Ubuntu is using my Intel card for everything. How do I fix that?